# Linking Fragment to Activity error

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

Im trying to attach a fragment to an activity, I've followed multiple tutorials and my code seems exactly the same (adapted to my app) than the ones in the tutorials and I cant find where my error is.

```
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
  import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
  import android.view.View;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_comments);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.id_layout_comments, new CommentsFragment())
                .commit();
    }
```

I get the error at the ".add(R.id.id_layout_comments, new CommentsFragment())" and it says: "cant resolve method add(int, package.CommentsFragment)".

This is the header of the class where I want to invoke the fragment:

```
 public class CommentsActivity extends FragmentActivity
```

And this is the one of the fragment itself:

```
 public class CommentsFragment extends Fragment
```

If you need any more information, let me know. Thanks a lot in advanced!

Comment: `public class CommentsFragment extends Fragment` ... obvious question: which `Fragment` ? ... native or from support library? ...

Comment: @Selvin Fragment class from the support library

Comment: Then such error is not possible ...

Comment: @Selvin I wish it wasnt possible, but certainly it is

Comment: programming is not some magic stuff .. it is not posible to have such error if `Fragment` which you are extending is the one from the support library ... check the imports !

Comment: @Selvin It is not magic stuff however the imports are correctly done and the error persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really you didn't need to extend FragmentActivity, just extend Activity is enough.

Look at this example:

CommentsActivity:

```
public class CommentsActivity extends FragmentActivity {
...
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_comments);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.id_layout_comments, new CommentsFragment())
                .commit();
    }
...
}
```

CommentsFragment:

```
public class CommentsFragment extends Fragment{
...
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_resource, container, false);
    return view;
}
...
}
```

That's it :D